# SQL запрос на решение задачи

Tags: sql

Решить задачу.
Учитывая, что один и тот же поставщик (Supplier), может поставлять несколько продуктов, цена которых будет отличаться, написать запрос, который выведет ID и имя поставщика, а также товар с самой высокой ценой, для данного поставщика. При этом, поставщик с самой высокой ценой за товар, должен находиться вверху списка.

Подсказка: возможно использование ранее рассмотренных функций агрегации, в качестве условия после команды “HAVING”.

Застрял пока тут....

```
SELECT Suppliers.SupplierID, Suppliers.SupplierName, Products.Price
FROM Suppliers, Products
GROUP BY SupplierName HAVING MAX(Price);
```

Comment: А по какому условию соединяются таблицы, должно же быть какое-то условие? А `HAVING MAX(Price)` это что вообще? Подсказка - надо `MAX(Price)` с чем-то сравнить, а не просто посчитать. Ну и сортировка записей ещё должна быть.

Comment: @CrazyElf *А `HAVING MAX(Price)` это что вообще?* Ну проверяет товарищ, не раздают ли товар бесплатно... имеет право.

Comment: ребята, я только вхожу в тестирование и посему обратился к вам...

Answer (score 0):

```
РЕШЕНИЕ:

SELECT s.SupplierID, s.SupplierName, p.Price
FROM Suppliers s, Products p
WHERE s.SupplierID=p.SupplierID GROUP BY s.SupplierName 
HAVING MAX(p.Price) 
ORDER BY p.Price DESC;
```

Comment: Проверте ваше решение на [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) и опубликуйте ссылку.